# How can I pass down through props a string of text with a link embedded within?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few sentences to pass down as a prop for a component and I would like the word "here" to include a link so the user can click.

I have tried the plus sign to concat the string, I have tried to use replace (example below)
but I cannot find any solutions.

The "replace" method leaves [object Object] in place of the word here.

Example code:

```
const textWithoutLink= "First part of the project is on another page. For a 
full description you can go here for a full explanation and walkthrough of 
the project."

const textWithLink= textWithLink.replace('here', <a href= 
'www.page.com'>HERE</a>)

return(
    <projectcard 
         text={textWithLink}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Send it as a [React fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) rather than as a string:

```
const fragment = <>
    First part of the project is on another page. For a full description you can go <a href="http://www.page.com">here</a> for a full explanation and walkthrough of the project.
</>;

<ProjectCard 
     text={fragment}
/>
```

---

**IF** for some reason that's impossible (but it really shouldn't be), you could use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) in `ProjectCard` instead, using the string with HTML in it. But it has that name, and is awkward to use, for a reason. :-)

---

Note that in the above I've assumed that your component is `ProjectCard`, not `projectcard`, as the latter being in all lower case would mean React/JSX would assume it was an HTML element, not a React component.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. It is an interesting method that has broadened my outlook on things you can pass through props.